# Android Array list returns Null after adding values

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am trying to add values to array list for ploting xAxis value in mpandroid chart but while debugging array list returns Null

While adding in forloop it shows value but after the end of forloop array list is empty Help me

**Code**

```
private ArrayList<String> getXAxisValues() {
final ArrayList<String> xAxis = new ArrayList<>();
final Intent intent = getIntent();
final String getUserId =  intent.getStringExtra("UserId");
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        HttpRequest req = null;
        try {
            req = new HttpRequest("http://abc.sc.in/abc.php");
            final String response = req.preparePost().withData("answerUserId="+getUserId).sendAndReadString();


            JSONArray myObjects = null;
            try {
                myObjects = new JSONArray(response);

                for (int ji = 1; ji < myObjects.length(); ji++) {
                    JSONObject jsonobject = myObjects.getJSONObject(ji);
                    final String Date = jsonobject.getString("date(answerDate)");
                    System.out.println("Date Response =====>: " + Date);
                   // The Values of Date (2 Dates [21,23]) here are shown while adding
                    xAxis.add(Date); 

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }






        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();


System.out.println("Here It shows [] after adding values ==============================>" + xAxis);

return xAxis;
```

}

Comment: actually your thread is not executed and before that you are returning xAxis

Comment: @user3676184 Is there any possibility of adding return inside thread or after thread execution

Comment: its your separate method or its in your main class

Comment: @user3676184 it is a seperate method

Comment: write your code outside the thread and it will work...

Comment: @MustanserIqbal http response is inside the thread can't acces values outside

Comment: ok. you can also make an interface to interact with UI

Comment: Or you can achieve all of this by using AsyncTask

Comment: were you able to fix this issue. If yes then any help with be greatly appreciated

Comment: @srbyk1990 yes I fixed this issue using AsyncTask method , refer user3676184 answer,the way I was handling thread was wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create `AsynchTask` task that will return `arraylist` 
like

```
public class DemoAsynch extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, ArrayList<String>>{

}
```

After that

```
ArrayList<String> abc = new DemoAsynch().execute().get();
```

in abc you will get all list and also pass your id whatever you required to that asynch

Comment: Calling `get()` method will hang Main Ui Thread which will cause "ANR" Dialog. so call `execute()` method without `get()` method and use `onPostExecute `

Answer (score 2):

I am not an Android guru but you missed the concept.

You really need to understand how an asynchronous call works. You are printing values and then the response coming back .

Try printing after the response came

```
for (int ji = 1; ji < myObjects.length(); ji++) {
                    JSONObject jsonobject = myObjects.getJSONObject(ji);
                    final String Date = jsonobject.getString("date(answerDate)");
                    System.out.println("Date Response =====>: " + Date);
                   // The Values of Date (2 Dates [21,23]) here are shown while adding
                    xAxis.add(Date); 
    System.out.println("Here It shows [] after adding values ==============================>" + xAxis);


                }
```

Comment: How can I do that ? can u modify and show how it will work ?

Comment: @vinod I already did. Look at the line `System.out.println("Here It shows [] after adding values ==============================>" + xAxis);
`

Answer (score 2):

> While adding in forloop it shows value but after the end of forloop
>   array list is empty

Because  `getXAxisValues()` method return value after calling `Thread.start()` instead of *wait until run method execution finish*.

Either use  `Callable` and `Future` classes to get status of running Thread before getting value or in Android, best way is do it using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) by implementing `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute`  methods

Comment: Upvote for listing possible ways ..I'll replace it with async thanks